# NestJS Dynamic template rendering in Fastify mode - res.render is not a function

Tags: nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify

I feel like [Model-View-Controller @ docs.nestjs.com](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) doesn't cover this use case - there is "Dynamic template rendering" section + Fastify but both combined together don't seem to work well.

I've tried the following snippet:

```ts
import { Get, Res } from '@nestjs/common'

@Get()
index(@Res() res) {
  if (isFoo()) {
    return res.render('template1.html', {var1: 'foo'})
  } else {
    return res.render('template2.html', {var2: 'bar'})
  }
}
```

and it fails with

> TypeError: res.render is not a function

Is there any way to fix it?

Just to be clear, the reason I'm not using `@Render` is because I need conditional logic inside that action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`res.render()` is the express method. For Fastify, you need to install [`point-of-view`](https://github.com/fastify/point-of-view) and use `res.view()`

Comment: Property 'view' does not exist on type 'FastifyReply....
can you help me config point-to-view for nestjs?

Comment: [The types are there, and they're doing declaration merging correctly](https://github.com/fastify/point-of-view/blob/master/index.d.ts#L4). So long as `point-of-view` is imported somewhere this should be fine